# Create KMZ from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a bunch of locations stored in "My Maps". Is it possible that I create a KMZ file that I can use in Google Earth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on the button for "link" above the map. Paste that link into the browser and hit enter. Then, add `&output=kml` to the end of the URL, and hit enter. You will be prompted to download a KML file, which will contain all of the points in the map.

Comment: This answer is now outdated as google has started using URL shortening . However I was able to use the URL from the "Email" button above the map

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that there's no convinient way of doing this provided by Google, I've created a tiny online app for export of your starred locations to KML: http://gexport.somee.com/
It's very primitive, but it does the job.

Comment: The link does not work