# Is there a way to export my starred locations from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, export, location

I have hundreds of locations starred in Google Maps.  I'd like to export the list of them so that I can import them into other software, like Google Earth or map applications on my Android phone.  Is there any way to do this other than manually clicking on them one-by-one?

If there's no official way, is there a workaround?  Google Maps for Android can access the starred locations, so maybe there's a way to rip them out of its database files?  Maybe some other software that can access it?

[This](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9131/create-kmz-from-google-maps) is very similar, but I am asking about Starred locations, they aren't in *My Maps*.

They recently changed it so that starred locations are listed along with other locations under "My Places", but I still don't see a way to export.

[image]

Comment: Currently there is no way to export Starred items in one batch.

Comment: @Dmitry: Is there a way to export them one by one?  I could write a Python script to automate it?

Comment: I cannot find a reliable way to do them individually either

Comment: They all appear in [Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/), but only as URLs with `cid` numbers like `https://maps.google.com/?cid=4350987349087335054`, and they're mixed in with all other bookmarks, but maybe a script could step through and follow each link and extract the name and coordinates?

Comment: @endolith: And the coordinates do appear in the page's source 3 times: `...,overlays:{sxcar:true,markers:[{id:'A',cid:'4350987349087335054',latlng:{lat:40.729879,lng:-73.991094}...`

Comment: Use Google Takeout https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout to export your saved/starred locations. I don't have enough credibility to provide an answer otherwise I'd do so.

Comment: As of (almost) 2023, you can export the starred locations directly with Google Takeout. For the other ones (hearts, flags, saved, etc), you get a CSV with only a link to... Google Maps! ;) If you want to actually get the whole data from those files, you can use a service like Export GM, it's currently free and works fine (https://exportgooglemaps.com).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Go to https://takeout.google.com/ and select only `Maps (your places)`

[image: Takout]

- After downloading and extracting zip, use http://nearby.org.uk/convert-saved-places.php to convert to KML

Comment: Exporting to .json is now the best answer, I think.  I know that's what I've used recently.  From Google Takeout, `Saved Places.json` and `Labeled places.json` both contain lat/lon and can be converted using https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/json-to-gpx  There may be some saved places that don't have title info, though?  I know some are just coordinates as the title.

Comment: Awesome worked great thanks. :-)

Comment: @endolith not sure if that is a Google Maps compatibility issue, but MyGeodata Converter does not perform well in this scenario. Titles and everything gets lost, in fact only raw coordinates remain. I found that the alternative mentioned in the answer gives more adequate output, at least it saves the title and the original Google Maps link.

Comment: @greatvovan Are the titles visible in Google Maps itself?  I've seen them disappear from the web lists, too

Comment: @endolith in my lists titles are there so far.

Comment: @HughW https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/166295/3317

Answer (score 21):

you can use Google Takeout to export your bookmarks as GeoJSON. Then you can use [this site](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/) to convert it to KML or GPX.

Comment: Much easier than the above solutions, although they surely work.

Comment: This webapp no longer works, possibly because it is hitting Google Maps on an HTTP URL. However it is now possible to export saved places via Google Takeout in GeoJSON format.

Comment: Thank you Jamie, I've updated the app and answer to point to Google Takeout instead.

Comment: This fails to label the places in the KML. Is there a better approach (now).

Answer (score 10):

[Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout) site has info how to move your data in and out of Google products.

In the case of Maps, you can export your saved places in GeoJSON format, which is then easily convertible to KML.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help

Comment: Actually it's way better this way, as you can download your saved places as geojson with all attributes.

Comment: This doesn't label the places in the Google Map (though the data is there in the GeoJSON as "Title"). Is there a way to ensure that the title ends up as the label for the location in the KML?

Answer (score 9):

A lot of the answers here are old and refer to the discontinued Google Bookmarks, which did seem to have this data usefully.

Using [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com), like the accepted answer suggests, gives you your starred locations. However, it *does not* include "want to go" places or locations marked with a heart.

[image: picture of "Saved" item in Takeout menu]

To get these other locations, you need to choose the menu item marked "Saved", which will give you a CSV file for each of these types of locations.

"Saved" seems like a really weird place to put this, I only noticed it because I searched for "maps" on the page. Based on the icon it may be related to Google Bookmarks somehow?

Comment: Thanks, sadly, mygeodata.cloud is not compatible with these lists, because they do not contain any geo data, just names and links.