# Is it possible for me to share all my starred locations on Google Maps with someone else?

Tags: google-maps

[This](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16177/is-there-a-way-to-export-my-starred-locations-from-google-maps) is a question about exporting, but what about a simple "share" feature?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [news story](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/google_maps_can_now_be_shared_on_plus.php), you can now share Google Maps on Google Plus. Google also has [a support page](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=144361) with instructions on how to share Google Maps locations and results. Another [Google support page](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024935?hl=en) even has information on how to allow collaborators to edit shared maps.

Finally [this blog](http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2011/04/share-google-map-with-your-group.html) notes that is a mobile app ([GroupMe](http://groupme.com/)) that provide map sharing functionality. I'm sure other apps are also available.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm not sure if this allows sharing of stars, but it does allow sharing of a lot of stuff that I previously wasn't aware of.

Comment: Google support page link is broken

Comment: @STEVER, thanks for catching that - I've updated the answer to include a working Google support page. The old support page (http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=144365) must've been removed.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the **Lists** feature, just launched in 2017, now allows you to share your stars with friends.

> https://techcrunch.com/2017/02/13/google-maps-lets-you-save-and-share-favorite-places-with-launch-of-lists/

See [**this post**](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7280933?hl=en) for more information.