# How to import Google Maps starred locations?

Tags: google-maps

I have a G Suite Google Account and a regular one. Because I don't need the G Suite Account anymore, I want to quit it. However, I have more than thousand stars / starred locations in Google Maps, I need to keep.

How can I transfer them to another Google Account? I [know how to export the stars](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/16177/60963) (using Google Takeout), but I found no way to import in any format.

A solution where the locations are in a custom map in My Maps or as a Layer is not suitable.

Answer (score 1):

If you exported it as KML or GPX file, you can import it at https://www.google.com/maps/d/ . Create a new map and import it as a layer.

Comment: It all works, but what next? Is there a way to actually convert this map layer to labelled places? Or at least to keep this layer on by default when I visit maps.google.com?