# Is there a way to export Travel Plans and other lists from Google Maps (including notes)?

Tags: google-maps, export

I have a number of items added to *Travel Plans* list of Google Maps (you can select it in the drop-down when you click *Save* button in the card), and now I would like to export them in a map exchange format (KML, GPX) to load into another application. The closest option I found was [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/121583/276638), but it is not exactly what I need because

- Google Takeout does not include *Travel Plans*, *Favourites*, and other lists including custom ones. It only includes *Starred* which is put into `Saved Places.json`.
- I can go through the list and add each item into *Starred* list, but: 1) it is a lot of manual work; 2) user notes will be lost (*Starred* list does not support notes and they need to be manually copypasted anyway as they are list-specific).

Is there a way to simplify my task?

Comment: Check this other answer on the same question you linked to: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/166295/159282. You just need to include the 'Saved' option in Google Takeout to get the other lists too.